# How to add two msi packges in suit installer for windows in installshield

Tags: windows, installation

I want to add two msi package in one suit installer package.And when install the package if user go with complete installation option then it install one msi package.If user select custom , there are two packages are listed and user should able to select and according to that installation go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the MSI is simple, go to the Designer view->Organization->packages and R-Click on Packages and add whatever type of installer your adding.

For Complete/Custom - use a "Property Comparison" condition in the "Eligibility Condition" for each package, ie: "Property Comparison" stringCompare PACKAGE1 = true

On the InstallType page, in the "Complete" and "Custom" buttons, click on the Events-Click option and click the green + sign to the right and select the setProperty action and set the properties to true or false for both buttons: "Complete" and "Custom"

So for the  Complete button, you would setProperty PACKAGE1=true and another setProperty PACKAGE2=false.

Custom you would setProperty PACKAGE1=true and another setProperty PACKAGE2=true.